# Writing and reading combo in Autoit

Tags: ini, autoit

I made this function:

```
Func ReadStats()
$Read1 = IniRead("C:\Config.ini", "Checkbox", "Check1", "1")
$Read2 = IniRead("C:\Config.ini", "Checkbox", "Check2", "1")
$Read3 = IniRead("C:\Config.ini", "Combo", "Comb1", StringSplit("-Xmx1024M|-Xmx2048M|-Xmx3072M|-Xmx4096M", "|"))
GUICtrlSetState($chosen, IniRead("C:\Config.ini", "Combo", "Comb1", StringSplit("-Xmx1024M|-Xmx2048M|-Xmx3072M|-Xmx4096M", "|")))
If $Read1 = Int(1) = 1 Then
    GUICtrlSetState($Checkbox1, $GUI_CHECKED)
Else
    GUICtrlSetState($Checkbox1, $GUI_UNCHECKED)
EndIf
If $Read2 = Int(1) = 1 Then
    GUICtrlSetState($Checkbox2, $GUI_CHECKED)
Else
    GUICtrlSetState($Checkbox2, $GUI_UNCHECKED)
EndIf
EndFunc
```

1. How do I get This to work

```
$Read3 = IniRead("C:\Config.ini", "Combo", "Comb1", StringSplit("-Xmx1024M|-Xmx2048M|-Xmx3072M|-Xmx4096M", "|"))
GUICtrlSetState($chosen, IniRead("C:\Config.ini", "Combo", "Comb1", StringSplit("-Xmx1024M|-Xmx2048M|-Xmx3072M|-Xmx4096M", "|")))
```

2. How can I get it to run the function on startup one time? If you wonder, I use this code to write info:

```
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        IniWrite("C:\Config.ini", "Checkbox", "Check1", GUICtrlRead($Checkbox1))
        IniWrite("C:\Config.ini", "Checkbox", "Check2", GUICtrlRead($Checkbox2))
        IniWrite("C:\Config.ini", "Combo", "Comb1", $chosen)
        Exit
```

The $Combo1 was created like this:

```
$Combo1 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("-Xmx512M", 24, 872, 161, 25, $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, "-Xmx1024M|-Xmx2048M|-Xmx3072M|-Xmx4096M")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GUICtrlSetData($Combo1, IniRead("C:\Config.ini", "Combo", "Comb1", -Xmx1024M|-Xmx2048M|-Xmx3072M|-Xmx4096M"))
```

Something like this ?
Cram

Comment: Thanks @Cramaboule. It solved the write problem. I also got it to read on startup so now I don't need to configure it every time.